# Не работает привязка с GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

Почему не работает привязка элемента к GridBagLayout? textField всегда отображается посередине окна.

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");

        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        frame.setLayout(gbl);


        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);


        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        c.fill   = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridwidth  = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        c.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        c.insets = new Insets(40, 0, 0, 0);
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.weighty = 0.0;

        gbl.setConstraints(textField1, c);

        frame.add(textField1);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, все дело в том, что layout занимает всю панель получается что одна ячейка растягивается на всю панель и располагает элемент внутри по середине ячейки. Вот пример с сайта Oracle

```
JButton button;
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
if (shouldFill) {
                //natural height, maximum width
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
}

button = new JButton("Button 1");
if (shouldWeightX) {
                   c.weightx = 0.5;
}
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);

button = new JButton("Button 2");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);

button = new JButton("Button 3");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);

button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
c.weightx = 0.0;
c.gridwidth = 3;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
pane.add(button, c);

button = new JButton("5");
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
c.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
c.gridx = 1;       //aligned with button 2
c.gridwidth = 2;   //2 columns wide
c.gridy = 2;       //third row
pane.add(button, c);
```

[Официальная документация GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)